# how to get the parameters of a request from a view in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and I want to know how to get the parameters of a request from a view.

This is my code for view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadPartialView", new AjaxOptions())) {
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1"/>  }
```

I want to get the value `Submit` or id `submit1` in action method `LoadPartialView` of the controller. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your view model or controller methods, you can get the value by doing the following:

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new AjaxOptions())) {
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1"/> 
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection f)
{
    var submitValue = f["submit"];
}
```

Alternatively, type your view to a model with a `submit` property and pass this to your controller method, doing something like the following:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public String Submit { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new AjaxOptions())) {
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit1"/> 
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    var submitValue = model.Submit;
}
```

The latter model is obviously more extensible as you can then group this value with other form values.

Comment: So, I should add the attribute "name" in my input tag. Thanks for your answer @AntP

Answer (score 0):

You need `name` attribute for any `input` field to be serialized by default to the `FormcCollection`, for example:

```
<input type="text" value="yourvalue" name="yourname" id="yourid"/>
```

Then you can retrieve such value in following way:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var val = formsCollection["yourname"];
    //...
}
```